# Propostion 1.6 on Atiyah's commutative algebra text

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a ring (commutative with 1) and $M$ a maximal ideal of $A$.
>   Let $x \in A-M $. Since $M$ is maximal, the ideal generated by $x$ and
>   $M$ is $(1)$, i.e. the entire ring.

I don't understand how that is true. If $x$ were a unit, certainly. However, $x$ could be contained in some other maximal ideal and is not guaranteed to be a unit. So how can we be sure that $x$ and $M$ can generate $A$?

Comment: the ideal generated by $x$ and $M$ strictly contains $M$, hence it must be the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal generated by $x$ and $M$ strictly contains $M$ (as $x \notin M$ by assumption). Then, since $M$ is maximal, by definition, any ideal containing $M$ must be the whole ring; thus, $(x,M)$ is the entire ring (as dezdichado said in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

$\mathscr M\subset A$  a maximal ideal implies that for any ideal $\mathscr J\supsetneq\mathscr M$, $\mathscr J=(1)$.

But if $x\in A\setminus \mathscr M$, then $(x,\mathscr M)\supsetneq \mathscr M$.

Comment: I would say "implies that" instead of "means that", since $A$ is not a maximal ideal.

Comment: @mathworker21thanks for the suggestion.   I'm not quite sure I see your point, though.    I chose "means that" because it really is the very definition.

Comment: $A$ satisfies the property that for any ideal $F \supsetneq A$, $F = (1)$, but $A$ is not a maximal ideal.

Comment: @mathworker21now I think I see your point.  You mean "implies" as opposed to "if and only if ".   See my edit.